# Is it possible to delete my searches from my Google account?

Tags: google-account, privacy, google-chrome

I notice that Google's Chrome browser actually stores all peoples searches in their Google account.

So for example, if I create a new user in Chrome, so a blank history, no bookmarks. And I log into Google as myself, like  blah@google.com  Then I do a search, it gives me suggestions based on other searches that I have done.

Is there any way to delete all these searches that Google has stored?

I can untick "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLSs typed in the address bar."

But I don't like that Google has stored them, and I'd like them deleted so that if that option were ticked, it wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: (in the meantime I will do all searches from duck duck go,  as google has gone way too far for me now. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Android phone or any other Google devices, there is a lot more information stored than just your search history.

The information is readily available (and you agreed to let them store is when you clicked 'agree' on the Terms and Conditions that nobody reads.  ;-)

You can view (and delete) what's stored about you on this page:

[**https://myactivity.google.com**](https://myactivity.google.com/)

Before deleting, you can export the wealth of data that is stored about you and your ussage, in various formats,  from this page:

[**http://takeout.google.com/**](http://takeout.google.com/)

The only way to prevent Google from storing information about *you specifically*, is to **not** log in to the device with your Google account.